# Best approach to make a fullscreen WPF app

Tags: wpf, grid, fullscreen, viewbox

I'm creating a full-screen application in WPF and i need to choose how to actually resize the contents to use all the available space on the screen.

As far as i know, there are 2 solutions:

- Grids with stars-dimensions
- ViewBox wrapper

I think they both do the job but depending on the application one is better than the other: when should the grid approach be used? And when the viewbox method is acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Grid is always going to give you more flexibility than a ViewBox, what if you want some components of your application to have fixed heights / widths? For example the panels at the side of visual studio do not change in size as the application window size changes.

Comment: Voted this as i think the in most cases the layout should be done by grids. Still, as Dave and kerem pointed out ViewBoxes come handy and can be used together with them or even alone for simple applications.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do some experimentation:

I agree with ColineE and karam:

Create a Grid using Stars for columnwidths and rows to help layout the program.

Then wrap the specific items you need to scale in viewboxes.

So, I guess this answer is 1/2 combined.

Check this sample code to see what I mean...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


<TextBlock Grid.Column ="0"  Text="Left"/>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column ="1" >
        <TextBlock  Text="Right"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot zoom with Grids and star dimensions. ViewBox can scale its content.